# Escape HTML tags in Smalltalk String

Tags: smalltalk, html-encode

I'm desperately trying to write a very basic method in Smalltalk to escape HTML tags ('<' and '>').

So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
escapeHtml: str
    |tags newString tmpString|
    newString := String new.
    tags := Dictionary new.
    tags at: '<' put: '&lt;'.
    tags at: '>' put: '&gt;'.
    tags keysAndValuesDo:
    [ :k :v |
        tmpString := str copyReplaceAll: k with: v.
        newString := tmpString
    ].
    ^newString
!
```

Unfortunately, it appears to only replace the very last item of the `tags` dictionary. What am I doing wrong? I should probably also point out that I have very little experience with Smalltalk.

The Interpreter of choice is 'syx'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you wanted to make something like

```
newString := str
```

and then in `keysAndValuesDo:` block:

```
tmpString := newString copyReplaceAll: k with: v.
```

because right now you are generating a `tmpString` for each key/value pair with only one key replaced. Than you assign it to the `newString`. To achieve your goal you should send `copyReplaceAll:` to the string that was processed on previous iteration. This can be done by sending a message to a `newString`, but for first iteration to work you should assign a value of an `str` to it.

**P.S.**
I also think that this cleaner version should work:

```
escapeHtml: str
    |tags newString|
    newString := str copy.
    ...
    tags keysAndValuesDo: [ :k :v | newString replaceAll: k with: v ].
    ^newString
```

Comment: I'm embarassed I didn't realize sooner that I was copying the same string all over the place. Thank you! It does indeed work now. :-)

Comment: @المستخدمغيرموجود I've also added a suggestion about the algorithm to the answer, maybe you'll like it ;)

Comment: I appreciate it, but unfortunately syx doesn't seem to have a definition for an in-place replaceAll (`#String:replaceAll:with:`), so I had to stick with the old code (however, I got rid of the superfluent `tmpString` variable). Again, I appreciate it, but syx merely lacks the proper method for it.